# The type or namespace name 'ServiceHost' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel'

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, iot

I'm trying to add a wcf service in an application for Windows Iot (Raspberry Pi) using Visual Studio 2015.

Because i can't add a reference 'on the usual way' (VS 2015 is not showing any), i added a nuget reference to System.ServiceModel.

```
        using (var host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost (typeof(HelloWorldService), _baseAddress))
        {

        }
```

How can i reach the ServiceHost? Resharper doesn't help me neither

[image: Nuget package list & Reference Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just found out that Windows iot doesn't support WCF (yet).